# PDO statement and reading results . basics

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this function whit PDO statement but i'm doing something wrong:(
And I also know what....

it's the : foreach ($result as $row); 
thats why i can't read : if($row['active'] === 'yes')

But in mine search on google and on stack i cant find the write answer.
Could somebody see what the right way is????
I'm still a little bit new to PDO :)

thnx in advanced.

```
include ('../../redir/mapping.php'); 
include ($dot2.$RMredir.$RFUserR);

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$Rhost.";dbname=".$RDB, $RDBsqlR, $RDBpassR);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($result as $row);

if($stmt->rowCount() === 0)
{
    $emailcheck = 'not_here';
}
else if($stmt->rowCount() === 1)
{
    if($row['active'] === 'yes')
    {
        $emailcheck = 'here_and_active';
    }
    else if($row['active'] === 'no')
    {
        $emailcheck = 'here_and_not_active';
    }
}
else
{
    $emailcheck = 'error';
}

return $emailcheck;
```

Comment: At the point where you're doing `foreach ($result as $row);`, `$result` isn't even defined (not to mention your foreach is empty).

Comment: did u read the question developerwjk? :)

Comment: did you read the PDO manual or any tutorial? `$results` doesn't spontaneously generate out of nowhere.

Comment: i know :) but i also said i know what the problem is and the question was,... how can i get to the results and read if the ['active'] === 'no'), i had written it down phoneticaly...

Comment: You need to use one of the functions like `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`...there are several different ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't fetching anything. In your code $result is empty:

use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to fetch the result. try:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$Rhost.";dbname=".$RDB, $RDBsqlR, $RDBpassR);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$emailcheck = array();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->rowCount() === 0){
    $emailcheck[] = 'not_here';
} 
else if($stmt->rowCount() === 1){
    foreach ($result as $row){
        if($row['active'] === 'yes'){
        $emailcheck[] = 'here_and_active';
        }
        else if($row['active'] === 'no'){
        $emailcheck[] = 'here_and_not_active';
        }
    }
}
else{
    $emailcheck[] = 'error';
}

var_dump($emailcheck);
```

Comment: why the `{` on the end of the line `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){`?

Comment: @developerwjk Was a typo. Corrected!

Comment: thnx nishanth matha.
your a great help.
i notticed you also use var_dump instead of return.
but is var_dump in a function better then the return command?

Comment: `return` should only be used in a function and `var_dump` is only for testing. If doing correctly You have to use `echo $emailcheck` . But in this example $emailcheck has been declared as array so you need to use a `foreach` loop to print the output or use `implode` to convert array into single string. Which one to use depends on your desired output